# Why am I getting INVALID_SESSION_ID with this rest api call?

Tags: rest-api

So I am able to get an oauth access token using a curl call such as the following:

```
curl https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -H "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=xxx" -d "client_secret=1xxx" -d "username=user@force.com" -d "password=xxxx"
```

I get a response with something like:

```
{"access_token":"accessTokenYYY","instance_url":"https://ap1.salesforce.com","id":"https://test.salesforce.com/id/xx","token_type":"Bearer","issued_at":"246890548714","signature":"GGfz/veli2sBM="}
```

When I use the access token I get back from the above curl call:

```
curl "https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Contact/" -H "Authorization: Bearer accessTokenYYY" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -d '{"lastname": "Smith", "email": "smith@force.com"}'
```

I get:

```
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

What am I doing wrong?  I am following the oauth flow as laid out in the documentation.

Comment: I see difference between your two curl commands in the salesforce api. The instance of the first is cs22 and the second one is ap1.

Comment: Ah, sorry that was a typo - they should both be ap1, I was changing a few things such as the access_token to sanitize the data

Comment: Pasted your cUrl into Postman - works perfectly. Are you updating you bearer everytime you're requesting sessiondId?
Other option - token might expire. Goto setup -> Session Settings and check how long your token is valid. By default it should be 2h.

Comment: Are you copying access token correctly?
Sometimes we miss when copying via console.
Have you tried via Postman? or any other Rest client?

Comment: Ok, great thank you guys for the ideas...So actually what I realized what it was, the actual access token had an exclamation point which caused curl utility to error out unless I escaped it with a backlash.  But the backslash sent with the curl request was causing the invalid session id.  When I tried the access token with no backslash escape in Postman, everything worked properly.

Comment: Any idea on how I escape the backslash in the access token (or not escape it) and send with the cURL utility?